# Image in a Table View Cell when using SearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, searchbar

I'm developing an app in Xcode in Objective-C.
The app has a TableView with an array of restaurants. My problem is that when I try to use the SearchBar I use the Title (name of the restaurant as a filter) but when I show the rows after the filter search, only the Title is right. The other label and the image in the cell is wrong (it shows me the correct title but the image and the other label (description label) is the same as the first row in the original tableview).

I have to change my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method but I don't now how to change it.

This is TableViewController called MainTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButton;

//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Images;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Description;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredRest;
@property BOOL isFiltered;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *RestTableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mySearchBar;

@end
```

This is my MainTableViewController.c

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "RestTableViewCell.h"
#import "RestViewController.h"

@interface MainTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

@synthesize mySearchBar, filteredRest, isFiltered;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"MadEat"]; /*Cambia el titulo del navigation controller*/

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}]; /*Cambia el color de las letras del navigation controller bar del menu principal*/

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:27/255.0f green:101/255.0f blue:163/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; /*Cambia el color del boton de la izquierda*/

    self.RestTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init]; /*Esta linea hace que en la tabla solo aparezcan el numero de filas que tienes establecidas, es decir, que las vacias no aparezcan*/

    /*Alerta que se muestra solo la primera vez. Está desactivada*/
    if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alert"]]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"alert"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Terms of use" message:@"The brands mentioned have no relationship with MadEat and the app has no any liability on that content." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Accept" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    _Title = @[@"80 Grados",
               @"90 Grados",
               @"B&B Babel",
               @"Babelia",
               @"Bacira",
               @"Bar Galleta",
               @"Bar Tomate",
               @"Barra Atlantica",
               @"BaRRa de Pintxos",
               @"BaRRa de Pintxos",];

    _Description = @[@"Barrio Malasaña",
                     @"Barrio Retiro",
                     @"Barrio Chueca",
                     @"Barrio de Salamanca",
                     @"Barrio Chamberí",
                     @"Barrio Malasaña",
                     @"Barrio Chamberí",
                     @"Barrio Malasaña",
                     @"Barrio del Pilar",
                     @"Barrio Retiro",];

    _Images = @[@"80_grados.png",
                @"90_grados",
                @"babel.png",
                @"babelia.png",
                @"bacira.png",
                @"bar_galleta.png",
                @"bar_tomate.png",
                @"barra_atlantica.png",
                @"barra_de_pintxos.png",
                @"barra_de_pintxos.png",];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{   
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return _Title.count;

    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        return filteredRest.count;
    } else {
        return _Title.count;
    }
}    

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    RestTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        cell.TitleLabel.text = [filteredRest objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        int row = [indexPath row];
        cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
        cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
        cell.RestImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];
    }

    cell.RestImage.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    cell.RestImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.RestImage.layer.borderWidth = 1;

    return cell;
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    /*Cambia el nombre del boton de la izquierda sin afectar al titulo del navigation controller*/
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Back", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]){
        RestViewController *restviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        int row = [myIndexPath row];
        restviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Description[row],_Images[row]];

    }
}

-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        //Set our boolean flag
        isFiltered = NO;
    } else {
        //Set our boolean flag
        isFiltered = YES;
    }
    //Alloc and init our filteredData
    filteredRest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString * restTitle in _Title) {
        NSRange restTitleRange = [restTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (restTitleRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredRest addObject:restTitle];
        }
    }

    for (NSString * restDescription in _Description) {
        NSRange restDescriptionRange = [restDescription rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (restDescriptionRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            //[filteredRest addObject:restDescription];
        }
    }

    for (NSString * restImages in _Images) {
        NSRange restImagesRange = [restImages rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (restImagesRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            //[filteredRest addObject:restImages];
        }
    }

    //Reload our table view
    [_RestTableView reloadData];
}

-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Finally, this is my TableViewCell.h called RestTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RestTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *RestImage;

@end
```

This is my problem graphically:

[image: The original TableView]
[image: The problem filtering by Title]

Comment: After checking if (isFiltered == YES) you are only setting the title. You also need to set the subtitle and the image as well

Comment: I know it that this is the part of the code that I have to change. But I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to filter the images array then maybe you can take the title and check its index in the original array by running indexofobject and then set the matching image and subtitle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you just apply the filter condition to the `Title` array, and not filtering the `Images` and `Description` array.

So you need to two more NSMutableArray to hold the filtering results for `Images` and `Description`.

But I recommend you to build a new `Model` for your results. Sample code for your reference:

#### Model layer: Restaurant.h

```
@interface Restaurant : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *desc;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *image;

- (instancetype)init:(NSString *)title descripiton:(NSString *)description image:(NSString *)image;

@end
```

#### Restaurant.m

```
@implementation Restaurant

- (instancetype)init:(NSString *)title descripiton:(NSString *)description image:(NSString *)image {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.title = title;
        self.desc = description;
        self.image = image;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

#### RestViewController.h

```
@interface RestViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Restaurant *DetailModal;

@end
```

#### MainTableViewController.m

```
@interface MainTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Restaurant *> *originData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<Restaurant *> *filteredRest;
@property (nonatomic, assign) Boolean isFiltered;

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

@synthesize mySearchBar, filteredRest, isFiltered, originData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    originData = @[
                    [[Restaurant alloc] init:@"80 Grados" descripiton:@"Barrio Malasaña" image:@"80_grados.png"],
                    [[Restaurant alloc] init:@"90 Grados" descripiton:@"Barrio Retiro" image:@"90_grados"]
                    ];
    filteredRest = [NSMutableArray new];
    isFiltered = NO;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return _Title.count;

    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        return filteredRest.count;
    } else {
        return originData.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    RestTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        cell.TitleLabel.text = [filteredRest objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].title;
        cell.DescriptionLabel.text = [filteredRest objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].desc;
        cell.RestImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[filteredRest objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].image];
    } else {
        cell.TitleLabel.text = [originData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].title;
        cell.DescriptionLabel.text = [originData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].desc;
        cell.RestImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[originData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].image];
    }

    cell.RestImage.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    cell.RestImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.RestImage.layer.borderWidth = 1;

    return cell;
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    /*Cambia el nombre del boton de la izquierda sin afectar al titulo del navigation controller*/
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Back", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]){
        RestViewController *restviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        if (isFiltered) {
            restviewcontroller.DetailModal = filteredRest[myIndexPath.row];
        } else {
            restviewcontroller.DetailModal = originData[myIndexPath.row];
        }
    }
}

-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        //Set our boolean flag
        isFiltered = NO;
    } else {
        //Set our boolean flag
        isFiltered = YES;
    }
    //Alloc and init our filteredData
    filteredRest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Restaurant *item in originData) {
        if ([item.title containsString:searchText]) {
            [filteredRest addObject:item];
        }
    }

    //Reload our table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

With building a new `model` object for your information is very efficient, so you don't need to apply there filter to three array, you just need to search once, and results will be kept kept in one array.

PS: One more tips for your coding style, naming the variable, object instance with starting lowercase, and naming the class with starting uppercase is best practise when writing OC codes. e.g., `TitleLabel` should rename to `titleLabel`, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have change the code using your model but I have an error in the  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In the: `cell.TitleLabel.text = [filteredRest objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].title;` Xcode gives me an error "Property 'title' not found on object of type 'id'". How can I change it? Thank you!

Comment: arr.. Sorry, I missed something when pasting the code here. I have updated my answer. You should redefine the `filteredRest` as `NSMutableArray<Restaurant *> *filteredRest`, same as `originData`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are filtering cell and reusing them.
You are just replacing text. You need to replace the image and data as well.

```
if (isFiltered == YES) {
        cell.TitleLabel.text = [filteredRest objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

} else {
        int row = [indexPath row];
        cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
        cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
        cell.RestImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];
}
```

I am not sure but I think you have not clearly understood concept of reusable cell. You will be reusing cell which are not in the view what that means is iOS framework will give you one of the already used cell so that it doesnt have to recreate cell everytime in your case thats first cell 80Grados.

So, after you receive that cell, you replace the title but leave all other content alone. That is why you see old content with new Title Label.

What you need to do here is create a wrapper class, which will have three properties text, description and imagefile name.

```
@class Restaurant
    @property NSString *title;
    @property NString *description;
    @property NSString *image;
@end
```

Combine your logic with this rather than treating all data as separate array. That will be extremely easy to maintain. In future you can easily fill that class with data coming from server, user entered or any otherway. Handling data in 3 different array is not very sustainable model.
So create wrapper class, fill data by creating NSMutableArray/NSMutableDictionary. Rather than putting title, fill entire wrapper object.

```
[filteredRest addObject: restaurantObj];
```

And change your code this way

```
Restaurant *r;
if (isFiltered == YES) {
        r = [self.filteredRest objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];         
} else {
        r = [self.restaurantList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
} 
cell.TitleLabel.text = r.title;
cell.DescriptionLabel.text = r.description;
cell.RestImage.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:r.image];
```

Let me know if any of the ideas are not clear. This is just a prototype, you will have to change your code in multiple places but would highly recommend making these changes sooner than later.